# If I input a float number when input is expecting an integer number, it updates the next float number value. Why does that happen?

Tags: c++, floating-point, integer

I am a complete newbie to C++ programming. So, I was just trying out some basic C++ coding and I wrote the below program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number1;
    float number2;

    cout << "Enter number1 (integer)\r\n";
    cin >> number1;
    cout << "Enter number2 (float)\r\n";
    cin >> number2;

    cout << "Number1 is "<<number1<<"Number2 is "<<number2<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I execute the above code and give say a number like "20.7" incorrectly instead of the integer that it expects when it prompts for number1,

the second cin statement gets skipped and number 1 is printed as 20 and number2 is printed as 0.7.

Why is that ? My expectation was the first cin should just make 20.7 as 20 and store it in number1 and second cin should not be skipped and prompt me for input.

Is that wrong expectation ? And why does this happen ?

Comment: I think standard input consumes what is required for integer then puts rest of string back in input for next consumption.

Comment: Why do you think the program should just skip input? If you want to understand how things work you should read some documentation instead of making assumptions. You'll go wrong **repeatedly** if you just assume.

Comment: You're skipping over a fundamental notion. You do **not** input a float number. You input **text** which the input code tries to interpret. If the text can be interpreted as an integer value, the code does that. Whatever text is left over after that is used for the next input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing float to an `int`. `cin` stops reading as soon as it sees '.' and the remaining number 7 is automatically taken as the input to the next `cin`.

You may want to flush the input buffers after each read if you think that the values may not match the expected type.

`std::cin.clear();` and `std::cin.ignore(100,'\n')`.

which would be

```
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(whatever_num,'\n');
```

More info can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/)

**Edit, for Pete's sake :**

1. `>>` Stream operator is the culprit.
2. All input is TEXT.
3. In the best case, read the input as TEXT and then parse/do whatever you want with it.
4. Avoid cin.clear() and cin.ignore().

Comment: `cin.clear()` has nothing to do with 'flushing input buffers'.

Comment: It explicitly does not, but it should be used in conjunction with fflush or cin.ignore, updated my answer.

Comment: Use `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` instead of an arbitrary magic number when you want to use `ignore` without the character limit.

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for the inputs. After using the cin.ignore, I could see that I could ignore the rest of the first input.

Comment: No, `cin` doesn't do any of this. The **stream extractor** (`operator >>`) reads the **text** and interprets it. The **text** in the input can be interpreted as an integer value, and the **stream extractor** stops reading when it sees something that can't be part of an integer. In particular, "You are passing float to an int" is simply wrong. The **text** can be interpreted as a floating-point value, but that also means that the initial part of the **text** can be interpreted as an integer value, and that's what the stream extractor does.

Comment: Also, `clear()` and `ignore()` is a sledgehammer. Input validation requires careful examination of the input. Protecting against unexpected forms of input generally requires reading the text into a string and looking at the string to decide what do with it. Interpreting part of it and discarding the rest may be appropriate, but that depends on what the extra input is and what it's supposed to be. `"3.2"` in input text is **not** a floating-point value and it's not an integer value. It is simply **text**.

Comment: @PeteBecker While what everything you say is true, simple language does help in communication. The end goal is to get the point across, while we can debate the validity of one's method of explanation over the other, The end result is that OP got the point. I just simply don't understand the down vote. just because you can.

Comment: You're missing the point. Input is **text**. Full stop. "Simple" explanations that skip over essential points are not helpful; they're just misleading.

Comment: @PeteBecker I have updated my answer. Thank you for your input. Everyone's a learner.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why, when an end user enters a floating point number where an integer is required, the program not only takes the integer into account but also assigns the stored floating points of the previously entered number to the next variable, is the buffer - which is essentially a temporary storage of data that is moved to another memory or data storage.

To fix this, you need to use the `cin.ignore()` function, which is a great function used to ignore and/or clear one or more characters from the input buffer.

If, for example, you add a `std::cin. ignore(1000,'\n')`, it would clear the buffer to allow the program to read and consider the next condition or statement. The number `1000` in the syntax is just there to ignore a specific number of characters (1000 characters) before the specified boundary, in this case the newline character `'\n'`, but it can, of course, be any number - depending on the number of characters you have.

So, take a look at my approach, below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
  int firstNumber;
  
  float secondNumber;
  
  cout<<"Please input an integer:"<<endl;
  
  cin>>firstNumber;
  
  cout<<"The entered integer is: "<<firstNumber<<endl;
    
  std::cin.ignore(1000, '\n');  //Ignore until next line
  
  cout<<"Please input a floating point number: "<<endl;
  
  cin>>secondNumber;
  
  cout<<"The entered floating point number is: "<<secondNumber<<endl;
  
  return 0;
  
}
```